# Placeholder - Stackoverflow Monitor - A Blue Prism Utility (CoE)

Tags: app, placeholder

**About**

An RPA utility for the Blue Prism Connected RPA solution, configured to search Stackoverflow content for product-specific questions and for posting relevant answers from the Blue Prism Community. Primary problem this utility is attempting to solve is identification of broader community questions related to usage of the Blue Prism tool, and for those identified, providing a mechanism for bridging the gap between the Stackoverflow community and the Blue Prism Community.

**License**

This utility is licensed under the MIT License

**Download**

The base source for this utility, which consists of a collection of Blue Prism artifacts (processes, objects, work queue, etc.) can be obtained from the Blue Prism Digital Exchange at the following: Stackoverflow Monitor RPA Solution. Once downloaded, edits will be required for the end-user's environment, etc., as noted in the user guide posted alongside the utility.

**Platform**

This utility is browser agnostic but does require a Blue Prism instance, which runs on the Windows platform.

**Contact**

This utility is Blue Prism Digital Exchange Community supported and questions, enhancements, etc. can be directed to the following: Digital Exchange Community.

**Code**

The utility was built in Blue Prism and included some custom C# code; all of which is included and fully accessible within the utility itself.

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://stackapps.com/q/8441/34061? You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged.

Comment: Hi, it is the same but the other app is owned by a different team and we wanted to keep a clear segregation of duties i.e. keys, tokens etc for audit. If both can refer to the same question, then that would be brilliant - is this possible?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks for the clarification and happy testing!